# I want one particular page to not take https

Tags: .htaccess, http, iframe, https

I have this one page which has an iframe inside of which a survey page is embedded, unfortunately i'm getting "Your connection is not secure" error inside the iframe.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue? By the way, the website is SSL certified, not the page i'm trying include inside the iframe. Also this is a php site not wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always going to have this problem when an HTTPS page references non secured content. You options are:

- move the page hosting the iframe (and its associated content) outwith HTTPS. Although, in theory a HTTP page should be able to reference HTTPS hosted javascript, CSS and images without emitting warnings, this will probably vary by browser
- move the survey page into HTTPS. I am guessing that you don't host this yourself - have you contacted the provider to ask if they can provide the service via HTTPS? Have you considered using a different provider?
- proxy the HTTP survey page via your server - this would require some clever configuration on the webserver or terminating the SSL connection in front of a proxy operating in reverse mode for your service and rewriting/forwarding mode for the survey. Basically, if you don't control the infrastructure this is probably a non-starter.
- re-implement the survey capability within your own site.

Bear in mind that as soon as your site is exposed outside of HTTPS it becomes vulnerable to more attacks.

.htaccess is not going to help - it overrides the behaviour within a vhost - the HTTP and HTTPS sites will operate in seperate vhosts.